# 2006 40gal Whirlpool Gas waterheater

Tags: water-heater

Drained tank to clean out. 2 drain pipes located outside wall keep dripping water. Pressure Release valve and drain valve not leaking. 
What could be causing leaking to the outside drains?

Comment: Have you looked under the water heater, Is the tank itself leak?

Comment: Thanks for timely response.  I forgot to mention the drain valve was dripping but since youtube video stated drips were common for up to a week I didn't worry.  I just now reopened drain valve and tightened it and its drip stopped.  I did notice very little water came out from drain valve. I tested Pressure release valve and heard water pressure inside tank and it stopped when I released the valve.

Comment: There is no sign of water leaking under tank.

Comment: YouTube would be wrong if saying that the drain valve would continue to drip.  Once shutoff, there should be no dripping.  Now that you retighten the drain valve and the valve no longer leaks, there should be no more leaking to the outside drain.

Comment: Is the pipe horizontal?  Maybe the water is just still dribbling out.